# Tool for forwarding UDP packets Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, port-forwarding, udp

Windows Server 2008 
I use portproxy interface to forward traffic , but I looked into the msdn page and I noticed it doesn't support udp protocol .

> protocol
>       Specifies the protocol to use. Currently, only Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) is supported.

Any suggestion how to froward udp traffic on Windows Server ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have no personal experience with it, but I'm seeing people saving favorable things about this [Simple UDP proxy/pipe tool](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm). It's worth a shot.

Comment: I was also trying to forward my DNS UDP packets from localhost:53 to OpenDNS_IP:5353 because my ISP redirects destination port 53 packets to their own server. Thank you for the information about such a great tool. Now I can use OpenDNS without setting up an intermediate router with dnsmasq and iptables rules.